Number of values of $n$ for which all coins can be flipped after finite moves.
Setup
$\bullet$ Let us take a square of side length $n$.
$\bullet$ Let us form a grid on this square by dividing each side into $(n-1)$ equal parts of each unit length.
$\bullet$ We can agree that $n^2$ number of squares can be formed in this process. No let's place a coin on each of this unit square.
$\bullet$ A 'move' consists of flipping three different coins together, which can be shaped like an 'L' and all its rotations(there are three rotations and L itself, so four possibilities).
Question
For what number of values of n can all the coins be flipped to tails, after a finite number of moves. If there are infinite values of $n$ for which this is possible, do the values follow any sequence?
My effort - Now, it is obvious that $n=2$ satisfies this,  with the moves $L, L_{1}, L_{2} $ and $ L_{3}$, where $L_{n}$ can denote the $nth$ anticlockwise rotations of 'L'. Now it is obvious that $n\neq1$ as we need atleast 3 coins to make moves. Now I don't know how to progress further. Please help me find the solutions and share the ideas.
This question came up when me and my friends were trying to create hard questions, so we have now idea what to do further. Thank you for your time and effort in advance.

This is possible for all $n\ge 2$.
Here is a five-step solution for $n=3$:
...   XX.   XX.   XX.   X..   XXX
...   X..   XX.   X.X   XX.   XXX
...   ...   XX.   XXX   XXX   XXX

It will also be useful to know that a $2\times 3$ grid has a solution:
...   XX.   XXX
...   X..   XXX

Past this point, for even $n$, we can divide the $n\times n$ grid into $2 \times 2$ boxes and apply the $n=2$ solution to each box.
Extend this division to $n+1$ by making all boxes on the right edge $1$ unit wider and making all boxes on the bottom edge $1$ unit taller. This divides the grid into $2\times 2$, $2\times 3$, $3\times 2$, and $3\times 3$ boxes, and we have a solution for all of these.
